# How to delete record in bulk using php

Tags: php, mysql

```
$id=array(1,3,5);
$sql="delete * from tablename where id = ".$id;
```

Now I want to delete all record in mysql whose $id are 1,3 and 5 at once..

Answer (score 2):

```
DELETE FROM `tablename` WHERE id IN (1, 3, 5);
```

With PDO:

```
$ids = array(1, 3, 5);
/* Create a string for the parameter placeholders filled to the number of params */
$place_holders = implode(',', array_fill(0, count($ids), '?'));

/*
    This prepares the statement with enough unnamed placeholders for every value
    in our $ids array. The values of the $ids array are then bound to the
    placeholders in the prepared statement when the statement is executed.
*/
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("DELETE FROM tablename WHERE id IN (" . $place_holders . ")");
$stmt->execute($ids);
```

Comment: well i need to pass the variable in id and they are alwz different..well thought solving using loop..

Comment: Props for use of bound parameters, to avoid problems with embedded data. (see http://xkcd.com/327/). The implode/array_fill is innovative, but could do with a little note of exactly what it is doing.

Answer (score 0):

in mysql try below:

```
DELETE FROM tablename WHERE id IN (1, 3, 5)
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/delete.html

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in

Answer (score 0):

deleting with an id:

```
DELETE FROM `tablename` WHERE id = 1;
```

with IN clause:

```
DELETE FROM `tablename` WHERE id IN (1, 3, 5);
```

delete all content from the given table

```
TRUNCATE table `tablename`;
```

deleting with given array of elements:

```
foreach($id as $i) {
    $sql="delete * from tablename where id = ".$i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$id=array(1,3,5);
$ids = implode(",",$id);
$sql="delete * from tablename where id IN (".$ids.")";
```

use the above code.

Comment: `DELETE * FROM …` is a syntax error. It should be `DELETE FROM …`.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to convert your array to the normal string,

```
$ids = array(1, 3, 5);
$strngId = implode(",",$ids);
```

now with this variable you can write delete query.

```
$sql = "Delete * from tablename where idfield IN (".$strngId.")";
```

Comment: `DELETE * FROM …` is a syntax error. It should be `DELETE FROM …`.